# Get Notified BEFORE the Text in a Windows::UI::Xaml::Controls::TextBox Changes

Tags: textbox, windows-store, textchanged, winrt-xaml-toolkit

Is there any way to get notified BEFORE the text in a `Windows::UI::Xaml::Controls::TextBox` changes (`TextChanged` and `TextChangedEventHandler` work great to get notified AFTER the text changes)?

The functionality I am seeking would be loosely equivalent to iOS's `shouldChangeCharactersInRange`.

Answer (score 1):

You could store the previous `Text` value from the last `TextChanged` event in a field and if you are not happy with the new value on `TextChanged` - revert to the old value. Alternatively - you could indicate an error without actually preventing a value change.